# How to migrate Test Cases from Azure DevOps to TestRail?

Tags: azure-devops, migration, azure-devops-rest-api, testcase, testrail

Our organization wants to move all the test cases from Azure DevOps to TestRail. How can I do that? When I checked azure DevOps rest APIs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) , there is no such api to pull all the test cases for a project.
Is there any tool that I can use to migrate test cases from Azure DevOps to TestRail?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered migrating to a test management tool by using a CSV file import? Azure DevOps allows you to export your test cases to a CSV file. You can learn more here:

[Export TestCases to Excel/CSV in Azure DevOps](https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/export-testcases-to-excel-csv-in-azure-devops/)

You can then import test cases as a CSV file into various test management tools. For example, in the test management tool [Testmo](https://www.testmo.com/) you can import test cases from a CSV file and easily map columns to fields:

[Importing CSV/Excel](https://docs.testmo.com/docs/user-guide/importing-migration/csv)

[image]

Full disclosure: I'm one the developers behind Testmo, so I'm using it as an example. But this approach should work with various other test management tools as well.

Comment: I cannot import to CSV from entire Test Plan, and our test plan has complex directory structure and it allows import only from specific directory not from entire test plan... so this solution is not feasible for us as we have 1000s of test plans with 1000s of directories in it. Can't keep downloading into csv millions of times.

Comment: Hi there; Testmo's import wizard actually fully supports complex directory structures and can import this in one go. You tell Testmo which column in your CSV file is the folder/folder hierarchy, and Testmo will automatically add the folders for all your cases.

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning from Azure DevOps to TestRail can be seamlessly accomplished without the need for any specific tools. TestRail provides the flexibility to import test cases, offering various options such as column mapping and value mapping for a smooth transition process.

The complete operation can be performed in 2 basic steps:

1. Export all test cases from Azure DevOps to an Excel or CSV file.
2. Import these exported test cases from the CSV or Excel file into TestRail.

For more comprehensive guidance, please consult the official documentation provided by TestRail. Detailed instructions and information about the transition process can be found there.

- https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/18691410380180-Migrate-from-Azure-DevOps
- https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7101779988372-Import-test-cases-from-CSV-or-Excel